# How to calculate days between dates from JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

I get information in a JSON and I'm parsing that to my app.

The date is a  string, so I know I need to calculate that in string.

```
      final s = all[index].lastdate;  <-- This is where my problem is, i cant access the json from this.
      final formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
      final dateTime = formatter.parse(s);
      final now = DateTime.now();
      final difference = now.difference(dateTime).inDays;

        final days ;
        if (difference == 0) {
          final days = "New";
        } else if (difference == 1) {
          final days = (difference.toString() + " day");
        } else {
          final days = (difference.toString() + " days");
        }
```

Comment: what is the type of `all`? I guess you need to use `final s = all[index]['lastdate'];` instead.

Comment: can you post some json data for the last date. Let us know how the format is and parse it as following